# An adventure movie about a kid who does what his computer game does in order to save his dad's life

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie was in English. The main plot has the kid (only elementary school age or younger) really into his Gameboy, or that sort of video game, and one day his dad disappears (or is kidnapped). In order to get his dad back, the kid has to separate from the video game, and actually go out and face the world. The most memorable scene was he packs his gear using the help of the game he played. He turns on the game on the computer, checks for the requirements, then he packs a rope just as the game requires it. In the end, I think he gets his dad back.

It was quite memorable, since even though it was meant to be kid’s film, it had a slightly dark tone, such as its theme about kidnapping, a game addicted kid, and facing the world on his own.

It was made in the 90's, and was at least a moderately successful film, since I was able to watch it on VHS in the pre-Internet era.

I initially thought Macaulay Culkin starred in it, but a Google search proved it wrong.

Comment: Note that there were plenty of "straight to video" movies produced in the early age of VHS. So even though you saw it on VHS, it may or may not have been "moderately successful".

Comment: Damn, I really want to say "Cloak and Dagger" from 1984 but I don't think it quite lines up.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the movie **Playing Dangerous (1995)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> A young scientific whiz (Mikey LeBeau) virtually single-handedly
>   defeats corporate mercernaries who take his family hostage to get a
>   blueprint for a top secret super-fast computer chip.  [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110847/?ref_=kw_li_tt)
>
> ---
>
> When his family is taken hostage in their home by corporate
>   mercenaries who are after a blueprint for a new kind of computer chip,
>   an eleven-year-old boy displays his genius by foiling the invaders
>   with toys, and other household items. [TCM](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/525549/Playing-Dangerous/)

Tráiler: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYESTQg5YEU)

Comment: thank you for your kindness, but this is not the film I'm looking for.